# Removing the last digit from all rows in a column in several files

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

On the 11th column of all files I have I would like to remove the last digit - a 0. I am not sure how to do this quickly?

Input file example

```
chr1    13281   C   G   20  4   16.670  S   28  3   9.680   S   Germline    0.006377004201320391    0.8803370017576622  19  9   2   1
chr1    13302   C   T   12  10  45.450  Y   20  11  35.480  Y   Germline    3.992679813441744E-8    0.8451888548995793  13  7   9   2
chr1    13402   G   C   114 0   00  G   153 2   1.290   S   Somatic 1.0 0.3311046995506439  139 14  1   1
chr1    136048  C   T   19  12  38.710  Y   32  7   17.950  Y   Germline    4.6433264291396187E-7   0.98655920157275    15  17  2   5
chr1    871269  A   C   12  2   14.290  M   26  2   7.140   M   Germline    0.058009817045962773    0.9000000000000099  4   22  0   2
chr1    881627  G   A   0   31  1000    A   0   43  1000    A   Germline    4.280406726905674E-44   1.0 21  22
```

output

```
chr1    13281   C   G   20  4   16.670  S   28  3   9.68    S   Germline    0.006377004201320391    0.8803370017576622  19  9   2   1
chr1    13302   C   T   12  10  45.450  Y   20  11  35.48   Y   Germline    3.992679813441744E-8    0.8451888548995793  13  7   9   2
chr1    13402   G   C   114 0   00  G   153 2   1.29    S   Somatic 1.0 0.3311046995506439  139 14  1   1
chr1    136048  C   T   19  12  38.710  Y   32  7   17.95   Y   Germline    4.6433264291396187E-7   0.98655920157275    15  17  2   5
chr1    871269  A   C   12  2   14.290  M   26  2   7.14    M   Germline    0.058009817045962773    0.9000000000000099  4   22  0   2
chr1    881627  G   A   0   31  1000    A   0   43  100 A   Germline    4.280406726905674E-44   1.0 21  22
```

Comment: note `1000` in last line will become `100`. is this also fine?

Comment: His example output shows 100 for this field.

Comment: yep I know but just in case, because it is not the same to convert `7.140` into `7.14` than converting a thousand into a hundred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk,

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]$/, "", $11)}1' file
```

Comment: It's a good idea, so ++. I suspect OP will want to set `OFS` to `\t` though; that data looks tab-delimited.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{10\}[^[:space:]]*\)0/\1/' YourFile
```

- `-i` option for an inline edit (and `--POSIX` due to GNU sed in this case)

Comment: You can include `-r` option to get rid of all that escaping and I believe it is `--posix` (lowercase).

Comment: posix and no escape on {,( is not compliant but you are right, it's a good option for GNU version